# Is NSFileManager thread safe?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, nsfilemanager

Is it ok to get an instance of NSFileManager via defaultManager and use it outside the main queue?

Is this code ok?

```
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(q, ^{

    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

});
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From [NSFileManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The methods of the shared NSFileManager object can be called from
>   multiple threads safely. However, if you use a delegate to receive
>   notifications about the status of move, copy, remove, and link
>   operations, you should create a unique instance of the file manager
>   object, assign your delegate to that object, and use that file manager
>   to initiate your operations.

Answer (score 9):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The methods of the shared NSFileManager object can be called from multiple threads safely. However, if you use a delegate to receive notifications about the status of move, copy, remove, and link operations, you should create a unique instance of the file manager object, assign your delegate to that object, and use that file manager to initiate your operations.

Answer (score 6):

Directly from the [`NSFileManager` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **Threading Considerations**
>
> The methods of the shared NSFileManager
>   object can be called from multiple threads safely. However, if you use
>   a delegate to receive notifications about the status of move, copy,
>   remove, and link operations, you should create a unique instance of
>   the file manager object, assign your delegate to that object, and use
>   that file manager to initiate your operations.

Comment: lol, within less than 2 minutes, three almost exactly same answers